# How to solve wordpress issue on localhost -Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

I Install wordpress on my local Host after installation complete i work on it for some time after that i shut down my pc and when i turn on my pc and start xampp after that start apache and mysql services and trying to open my wordpress site on local host than its say `Error establishing a database connection`

After that i check my wordpress database details those details are corect.

here is code

```
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wpdatabase' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'admin' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'admin' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

Now i did not understand how to resolve this issue

Comment: tro to change localhost with 127.0.0.1. Sometimes it help

Comment: Sir i try to do this on my mysql config. file but when i put this host 127.0.0.1 than i restart mysql its automatically shuting down not starting mysql after that process

Comment: I'm sorry but changing the content of that wp-config.php file should NEVER interfere with your mysql booting up. If your mysql is crashing then you found the issue. It's not a problem of wp-config but something related to your xamp mysql configuration :)

Answer (score 0):

try to repair the db:-

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

just add this code into wp-config file

Comment: sir i add this code on wp-config file but issue don't get resolve same error occurs again

Answer (score 0):

okk, so here are very quick steps to run out of this problem:-
first make sure your localhost is working fine, just open database by phpmyadmin if db is opening that means you dont have any issue in the connection,
2) check for correct password and username.
3) Very last step if both above points wont work just go to file directory wp-content/plungins and rename the folder name plugins to pluginsxyz and then check . I am definatly sure this point will help you